# Encrypting and decrypting the data using different Cipher algorithm in PGP

Tags: encryption, pgp

I am trying to get my head over this and hope someone can explain what is happening. I have a PGP key pair from which I encrypted a message after specifying the cipher algorithm like AES_128, AES_192 or TWOFISH. Later, I tried to decrypt that encrypted message using a different cipher algorithm and I could still see the message.

How is this possible if I am encrypting a message using cipher AES_128 then how is it getting decrypted using the CAST5 cipher algorithm? I was expecting it to fail or at least get some garbage data however I could see the exact plain text that I encrypted in the first place.

Comment: Can you share the specific command invocations you used?

Comment: @chuckx, I am using PGPLib a .NET library by DidiSoft for PGP operations. Using the library I could supply the cipher algorithm to be used before encrypting the data like PGPLib lib = new PGPLib{ Cypher = CypherAlgorithm.AES_128 };. The thing is I could decrypt the same message by setting a different algorithm on the PGPLib instance before decrypting.

Comment: In that case, it would be best if you could share code, preferably in the form of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).